# Why cant i delete the elements of my list using pop() function in this code?

Tags: python

So, I was trying to solve some coding problems and came across this one:

**Question:**

> Xenia the beginner mathematician is a third-year student at elementary school. She is now learning the addition operation.
>
> The teacher has written down the sum of multiple numbers. Pupils
> should calculate the sum. To make the calculation easier, the sum only
> contains numbers 1, 2 and 3. Still, that isn't enough for Xenia. She
> is only beginning to count, so she can calculate a sum only if the
> summands follow in non-decreasing order. For example, she can't
> calculate sum 1+3+2+1 but she can calculate sums 1+1+2 and 3+3.
>
> You've got the sum that was written on the board. Rearrange the
> summans and print the sum in such a way that Xenia can calculate the
> sum.
>
> Input The first line contains a non-empty string s — the sum Xenia
> needs to count. String s contains no spaces. It only contains digits
> and characters "+". Besides, string s is a correct sum of numbers 1, 2
> and 3. String s is at most 100 characters long.
>
> Output Print the new sum that Xenia can count.

So basically if I input 3+2+1, the output should be 1+2+3.

My solution was basically removing the '+', sorting a list, and then use the `join` function. The problem is that my code does not remove the '+'. I tried iteration with pop and delete and simply using the `remove` function but nothing works.

**Here is my code:**

```
a=input()

for i in range(0,len(list(a))):
    if list(a)[i]=='+':
        list(a).pop(i)

b=[int(x) for x in list(a)]
b.sort()

print('+'.join(list(a)))
```

I tried printing at every step and the problem is that the "+" is not removed. Please help.

> ERROR MSG: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'

[this means that the '+' was not removed]

Comment: `+` was removed from `list(a)` but not from the `a` itself. So when you convert your `a` into a list `+` will still there. You have to save the modified `list(a)` for later use.

Comment: `list(a)` creates a new (copy) list of `a`.
Basically you create a list, pop its last element and throw this list away.

Comment: A better approach anyway is `terms = a.split('+')`

Comment: one-line solution: `print("+".join(sorted(a.split('+'), key=int)))`

Comment: @Daniel didnt know about 'key' attribute thanks.